# COM component cannot call .NET component on Win 2008 R2

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com, interop, regasm

Question after much research without any luck. We have a classic ASP site that uses a COM component. This COM component needs to call .NET component using CreateObject(".NET component"), from classic ASP.

However, we are seeing this in the event viewer:

> Error code: -2146233036 - Automation error

I use Regasm to register the .NET wrapper and the type library (successfully checked against registry and gac). I also added the .NET component to COM+ application (no luck as well). The COM component is also registered (regsvr32).

I'm not sure what I might be missing. Also, the COM component can't seem to make calls to other COM components. I think this is related but can't seem to narrow it down. I apologize but I'm a .NET guy and had to read bit on COM.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am Not a COM or COM+ person, but a few posts i have seen talks about running the regasm command with /codebase option. Did you try that ? [in social/msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c5c16d7-4029-4b6f-9a29-55a1c27718b5/error-2147024894-80070002-automation-error?forum=vbinterop) , [RegAsm - When is the /codebase option applicable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939699/regasm-when-is-the-codebase-option-applicable)

Comment: Could be many things, but this usually happens when your .NET can be constructed. Typical reasons are exceptions thrown from constructors (especially if you have a static ctor), missing default constructors or missing dependency assemblies. Are all assemblies needed by your component properly deployed?

Comment: Thank you folks! The problem happened when we migrated from a 32 bit OS (2003) to Win 2008 R2 64 bit. Code-wise, nothing has changed in about 3-4 years. I did try the codebase option in regasm as well. I have the .NET component installed (checked GAC as well) using regasm tool (generated and registered type libraries). No luck as of today. Wonder if the vb6 component is not installed properly. I'm out of ideas. my CreateObject VB6 call to the .NET component gives me a null object (upon debugging)